# One liner to convert lower case to upper case recursively on files ending with a particular extension

Tags: perl

I've been trying to get this working for some time now. I see posts for search and replace in Perl recursively using `perl -pie` but I can't get it to work.

This is what I have:

```
perl -pie 's/a-z/A-Z/g' *.ods
```

This says no match.

Comment: What do you mean by "_recursively_" ?

Comment: What do you want to convert to lowercase, the names of files or their contents? Both require different approach. The one liner you mention converts to lowercase *the contents* of files in current directory, ending with `.ods`.

Answer (score 3):

- `-i` takes an optional "argument" (the extension to use for the backup). If you don't want a backup, you need to place a space after the `-i`.
- `s/a-z/A-Z/g` replaces all instances of the string `a-z` with the string `A-Z`.

Fix:

```
perl -i -pe'tr/a-z/A-Z/' *.ods
```

Answer (score 2):

This could do it.

`perl -p -i -e 'tr/a-z/A-Z/' *.ods`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.
firstly, it's not Matching *.ods..and when I just executed perl -p -i -e 'tr/a-z/A-Z/', it did not show any issues, but it did not seem to change the file names.

does this command change contents of the files or the filenames itself ??

Comment: It changes the content of the files matching files with extension _.ods_ on a path specified. This should be more clearer,  `perl -p -i -e 'tr/a-z/A-Z/' /path-to-file-directory/*.ods`

Answer (score 2):

The examples given so far will operate on the contents of the file vs the file name. While you can indeed use Perl to achieve what you want, I'd advise to just use bash itself, assuming that's an option.

If you really want to use Perl for this I would make a script vs a one-liner:

## Perl example

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub rename_file_extensions {
    my ( $dir, $orig_ext, $new_ext ) = @_;
    chdir($dir) or die "Can't chdir to $dir $!";
    opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Couldn't opendir: $!\n";
    for my $file ( readdir $dh ) {
        if ( -d $file && $file !~ /^\.+$/ ) {
            rename_file_extensions( "$dir/$file", $orig_ext, $new_ext );
        }
        else {
            if ( ( my $txt = $file ) =~ s/$orig_ext$/$new_ext/ ) {
                rename( $file, $txt ) or die "Can't rename: $!";
            }
        }
    }
    closedir $dh;
}

rename_file_extensions( $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1], $ARGV[2] );
```

The script above would be called as `perl script.pl  /path_to_files ods ODS`. It will recurse through all directories in /path_to_files; renaming each instance of `file.ods` to `file.ODS`.

## Bash only example

`find . -name "*.ods" -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.ods}".ODS' - '{}' \;`

Cheers

Comment: Context-flexible alternatives to the higher-level task. Excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do want to modify the *name* of files instead of content, here's another way using the `find` and `xargs` commands and a Perl script called `rename` (it is an example script that comes with Perl and available on Debian via the `rename` package).

```
% find -type f -name '*.ods' | xargs rename -n 's!(.+/)(.+)!$1 . lc($2)!e'
```

The advantage of using this script is you can do a simulation (dry-mode) first before actually changing your filenames, using the `-n` option. Once you confirm that the result is what you intended, you run again without the `-n` option.

Sample files:

```
% find
.
./Sub1
./Sub1/FOUR.ODS
./Sub1/three.ods
./Sub1/Two.ods
./sub2
./sub2/five.ODS
./sub2/Five.ods
./One.ods
```

Sample output:

```
rename(./Sub1/Two.ods, ./Sub1/two.ods)
rename(./sub2/Five.ods, ./sub2/five.ods)
rename(./One.ods, ./one.ods)
```

Yet another alternative is using the [perlmv](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlmv) script, available from CPAN (install it using e.g. `cpanm -n App::perlmv`). This script is glorified form of `rename` and supports recursive mode so you can skip using `find` and `xargs`:

```
% perlmv -d -R -e'$_ = lc if /\.ods$/' .
```

The `-d` is for dry-run mode, the `-R` is for recursive. Sample output:

```
INFO: chdir `/zpool_host_mnt/mnt/home/s1/tmp/ods/.` ...
DRYRUN: move `One.ods` -> `one.ods`
INFO: chdir `/zpool_host_mnt/mnt/home/s1/tmp/ods/Sub1` ...
DRYRUN: move `Two.ods` -> `two.ods`
INFO: chdir `/zpool_host_mnt/mnt/home/s1/tmp/ods/sub2` ...
DRYRUN: move `Five.ods` -> `five.ods`
```

Once you are sure you get the right results, remove the `-d` option.